# How to display ActivityIndicator inside PrepareForSegue?

Tags: ios, swift

I perform simple check on user data before navigationg to next VC.

Problem: No ActivityIndicator show up at the count of 1 to 15 second.

How to solve this kind of problem? Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
//          VC(1)  -- >  VC(2) 

// use BtnGo in VC(1) Control-drag to VC(2) 
// Name the Segue : SegueToVC2


// when BtnGo is click, I will do simple validation.

//-- do validation

override fun shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?)-> bool
{
     activityIndicator.hidden = false  (A)

   if identifier == "SegueToVC2" {

    // check user input 

    if username.isEmpty {


        return false

    }else {

      return true
   }

 }

  return true

}
```

In `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

 disptach_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() {

 self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()  (B)

  }


  if (segue.Identifier == "SegueToVC2) {

    // goto VC(2)    (c)

  }

  activityIndicator.stopAnimating() (D)

}
```

Comment: Does `// goto VC(2)` cost a lot time?

Comment: If everything is ok, it take 12-15 second to next VC(2) and in VC(2) it has a Http request.  Even it take 12-15 second, can I show the activityIndicator in VC(1) before going to VC(2)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the property `hideWhenStopped` on the `UIActivityIndicatorView` instead of the hidden `property` : it will be displayed when you call `self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()` and will be hid when you call `self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()`

Also, you should call `self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()` within `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` and hid it in `prepareForSegue`, after your calculs/request are done.

If the problem still occurs, try to use `performSelectorOnMainThread` to show your `UIActivityIndicatorView`